# No such file or directory in Pydev

Tags: eclipse, command-line, arguments, pydev

I have a file in my project directory that I want to run a script on:

```
myproject\file1
```

The script is in `myproject\src\script`.
When I go to `run configurations -> arguments` tab and put `file1`, I get an:

```
IOError: No such file or directory: 'file1'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/pydev-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg02698.html), try setting the working directory of your run configuration to:

```
${project_loc}/src/script
```